# SqlNullValueException: "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I cannot understand why the context of my EntityFramework code is resulting null.
When I try to retrieve a list of the table from database (SQLSERVER) the code throws the error:
"Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

```
using (DbConnectionContext context = new DbConnectionContext(configuration)) //configuration -> IConfiguration 
        {

            return context.Employee_Mail.ToList();
        }
```

Fine. Maybe there's some issues with the connection string, but I've another block of code with the insert into table and it works!

So I tried to put inside the code before the "insert into" lines:

```
using (DbConnectionContextcontext = new DbConnectionContext(configuration))
        {
            
            var table = new Employee_Model()
            {
                USERNAME = "contoso@contoso.com",
                employee_typology = "some placeholder",
                employee_code = "1234",
                insert_date = DateTime.Now,
                ID_EMAIL = "0000",
            };

            context.Employee_Mail.Add(table);
            context.SaveChanges();
            

            return context.Employee_Mail.ToList();
        }
```

After the "insert into" MAGICALLY the select and the context retrieve the list with all the employee...
What's the point? Why before that it throws the error saying that the context is null and after an "insert into" works?
*Randoms bullshit meme comes to my mind*

Comment: it isn't saying that the *context* is `null` - it is saying that *some value* is `null` when it isn't expecting it to be; however, yes it is odd that it behaves differently with/without the `Add`; are they talking to the same copy of the database? I wonder if this is something more like one of the rows has a `null` for `insert_date` or some other column that is defined as non-nullable in your model

Comment: Apropos random BS.  You have a Employee_Mail Table that you add a Employee_Model object to and the variable for that Entity is called table? Sometimes quirky naming makes it hard to be not distracted and still see the maybe obvious problem.

Comment: @Ralf that's not the point, ok that's not the best naming convention, but I have to undestand why it behaves in 2 different ways with Add() method or not.

Comment: @MarcGravell yes they are talking to the same database, the connection string doesn't change. The application console starts with that select on the db

Comment: The point is that EF Core enforces nullability and one of the query results has a null while the entity type (which isn't shown here) has a non-nullable type like `string`. That's what a `SqlNullValueException` is about

Comment: @Cardo as for the same database - you'll have to post code we can take, compile and run to reproduce the error *without* making assumptions. Obviously this doesn't happen in general, none of our projects would work. Just as the non-null property was missed, a connection to a file-based or development database may be missed. Or each part of the code starts with a new database

Comment: `The application console starts with that select on the db` what database is this? What's the actual connection string? Are you using a User Instance database, connecting to an `mdf` file stored in the project folder? In that case you're connecting to the copy inside `bin/Debug` or `bin/Release` created every time you build your project.

Comment: Or perhaps the code is wrapped in a transaction that's never committed? The name `DbConnectionContext` suggests that DbContext is mistaken for a connection object. It's not, it *uses* connections to load or save data only. DbContext is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work that uses optimistic concurrency.